# Installing latest rust nightly complains about missing rls component

Tags: rust, rust-rocket, nightly-build, rust-language-server

Trying to compile: https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/tree/master/examples/hello

Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
rocket = "0.4.10"
```

Complains that I need rust nightly

```
$ cargo build
...
  Error: Rocket (core) requires a more recent version of rustc.
  Installed version: 1.54.0 (2021-05-17)
  Minimum required:  1.54.0-nightly (2021-05-18)
```

I have done a local directory override

```
$ rustup override set nightly
```

I am running nightly 2021-05-17 but I need 2021-05-18

```
$ rustup show
...
active toolchain
----------------

nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (directory override for '/<redacted>')
rustc 1.54.0-nightly (3e99439f4 2021-05-17)
```

I've tried all sorts of commands to get a more recent nightly

```
$ rustup update
$ rustup update nightly
$ rustup toolchain install nightly-2021-05-18
```

There is some weird stuff when I do `rustup update nightly`

```
$ rustup update nightly 
info: syncing channel updates for 'nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: latest update on 2021-05-23, rust version 1.54.0-nightly (e4ca1662f 2021-05-22)
info: skipping nightly which is missing installed component 'rls'
info: syncing channel updates for 'nightly-2021-05-22-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: latest update on 2021-05-22, rust version 1.54.0-nightly (5dc8789e3 2021-05-21)
info: skipping nightly which is missing installed component 'rls'
info: syncing channel updates for 'nightly-2021-05-21-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: latest update on 2021-05-21, rust version 1.54.0-nightly (40d230204 2021-05-20)
info: skipping nightly which is missing installed component 'rls'
info: syncing channel updates for 'nightly-2021-05-20-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: latest update on 2021-05-20, rust version 1.54.0-nightly (f94942d84 2021-05-19)
info: skipping nightly which is missing installed component 'rls'
info: syncing channel updates for 'nightly-2021-05-19-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
info: latest update on 2021-05-19, rust version 1.54.0-nightly (4e3e6db01 2021-05-18)
info: skipping nightly which is missing installed component 'rls'
info: syncing channel updates for 'nightly-2021-05-18-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'

  nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu unchanged - rustc 1.54.0-nightly (3e99439f4 2021-05-17)
```

Complains about `skipping nightly which is missing installed component 'rls'` and I have no idea how to resolve this

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry for the wall of text, see ***The solution to your problem*** below if you only want a quick fix. You might also look at [the rustup book](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/concepts/channels.html#nightly-availability), it contains information about this type of problem.

---

You are trying to install a nightly version of Rust. In nightly versions, the availability of non-essential components of Rust, such as the [Rust Language Server](https://github.com/rust-lang/rls) (or short `rls`) is not guaranteed – if they fail to build, the nightly is shipped without them. You can see [here](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup-components-history/) that `rls` indeed was not part of the last few nightlies. The last day a nightly was shipped with `rls` was `2021-05-18`, which is a build from the day before, so `2021-05-17` (a bit irritating, but this [seems to be accepted behavior](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/1637)).

Your rustup installation seems to be configured to include `rls`. Therefore, when you tell `rustup` to update your `nightly` toolchain, rustup selects the newest nightly **containing `rls`**. There are no such nightlies newer than your currently installed `nightly-2021-05-17`, therefore, `rustup` does not update the toolchain.

## The solution to your problem

- If you don't need `rls` (it's only necessary for auto-completion in IDEs and stuff like that), there are multiple solutions to your problem:

  - You can remove the `rls` component from your nightly toolchain: `rustup component remove --toolchain nightly rls`
  - [The rustup book](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/concepts/channels.html#nightly-availability) also has some more solutions:

    > If [a previously installed component] is missing, rustup will automatically search for an older release that contains the required components. There are several ways to change this behavior:
    >
    > - Use the --force flag to rustup toolchain install to force it to install the most recent version even if there is a missing component.
    > - Use the --profile flag to rustup toolchain install to use a different profile that does not contain the missing component. For example, --profile=minimal should always work, as the minimal set is required to exist. See the [Profiles](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/concepts/profiles.html) chapter for more detail.
    > - Install a specific date that contains the components you need. For example, rustup toolchain install nightly-2020-07-27. You can then use [overrides](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html) to pin to that specific release.
- If you do need `rls`, you are in a bit of a tight spot. You might want to [use a override](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html) for your project, in effect using different Rust builds for building your code and for running `rls`. However, this will probably not work – `rls` may need to build your project dependencies for autocompletion, and Rocket will not allow that with older nightlies. I don't really have a solution for this case – you may need to stay on an older version of Rocket or stop using `rls` for now, until there is a newer Rust nightly shipping with `rls` again.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I managed to get around this by using rocket 0.5 directly from github which does not require nightly. However, this information will be useful if I run into issues like this in the future.

Comment: When executing "rustup component remove --toolchain nightly rls", I get the following: "error: toolchain 'nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin' does not contain component 'rls' for target 'aarch64-apple-darwin'; did you mean 'rustc'?"

Comment: https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup-components-history/ doesn't show rls anymore.

Comment: @Dereckson Looks like rust-lang.github.io/rustup-components-history only shows the last 7 days. `rls` was last available on 2022-02-22, so it isn't visible there anymore.